# Download data from ampd.epa.gov using R code

Tags: r, download

Is there a way to download these data https://ampd.epa.gov/ampd/?bookmark=12264 automatically using R code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The simplest way could be using `RSelenium`. But the process can be tedious since you need to use `css` or `xpath` to find a lot of different elements on the web page, simulate clicks or switch frames if there are iframes.